# Java: convert date string to characters

Tags: java, string, date, character

I'm looking for a way to convert a formatted date to characters in Java.

```
String fdate = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS")
            .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
            .format(
                Instant.now(Clock.systemUTC()));
```

This gives me a like string of 17 characters, only made of numbers. I'd like to "convert" the numbers to characters, like in hexadecimal but using all characters, in order to make the date shorter (in fact I need to generate a unique id with the fewest characters... customer constraint).

WHich would return me like:

```
Z5G1BJ9F...
```

I don't need to be able to convert back to "usual" string next. Only usual characters are allowed [1-9a-zA-Z].

Is there an easy way to do it?

Thx.

Comment: Have you considered just working with UNIX timestamps?  It might be even shorter than what you are proposing, but would be easier to work with.

Comment: Yes I did, and I'd like to apply the same to a timestamp. From an Instant I can get the epochMilli (long) and the nano seconds (int), I'd like to "encode" both to characters also

Comment: So what is the issue? Just take that number and convert to base 36.

Comment: Tip: If your goal is to make a universally unique identifier, just use, well, a [universally unique identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). The original Version 1 UUID  combines the current moment, a MAC address, an arbitrarily incrementing number, and a few other bits to determine a 128-bit value. Don’t reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date in `yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS` format might still result in duplicate IDs.

To generate a unique id with the fewest characters use a database sequence to generate the next number (or implement it yourself using a file). You won't get a shorter unique number if your sequence starts from 1 and increases by 1.

If your constraint is to use `[1-9a-zA-Z]` character you can apply [Base58](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base58) or similar encoding. Unfortunately Base64 uses `+`, `/`, and potentially `=` so it doesn't fit your requirement. An example implementation of Base58 can be found in [BitcoinJ project](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/core/Base58.java):

```
BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(3471844090L);
assertEquals("16Ho7Hs", Base58.encode(bi.toByteArray()));
```

Comment: Thx, exactly what I was expecting